# What is the difference between declaration of module with and without variable in angularJs?

Tags: angularjs

correct me If I am wrong..

```
--Setting a module
    var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
```

// here brackets means module does't exist just go and create it, and the empty array is the list of module it depends on

```
--Getting a module
    var app = angular.module("myapp");
```

//and if brackets are not here mean module exist just find it.

but what is the difference between below lines:-

```
  var myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);
  myapp.controller("MyController", "$scope", [function($scope){
    //TODO
  }]);

  and 

  angular.module("myapp", [])
  .controller("MyController", "$scope", [function($scope){
    //TODO
  }]);
```

I think we should use variable only if our module is divided in multiple files.
but I am not sure if it will really makes any difference.

As per [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#modules) we should not use variable while declaring a module.Could anyone please clarify?

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to use `myapp` in your first example? Also, your second example would not work, you would need to chain the controller definition with the module definition in the previous line (hint: no semicolon, no `app` variable). Leaving these two issues aside, both examples are equivalent and produce the same result.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: You still need to correct the variable name in your first example. ;)
The only difference between the examples is that one creates a new variable in the global scope, which you should usually avoid, but you can also prevent this from happening by wrapping your declaration into an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

Answer (score 2):

> --Setting a module
>
> ```
> var app = angular.module("myapp", []);`
> ```
>
> Here brackets means module does't exist just go and create it, and the empty array is the list of module it depends on
>
> --Getting a module
>
> ```
> var app = angular.module("myapp");`
> ```
>
> // and if brackets are not here mean module exist just find it.

Correct

> we should not use variable while declaring a module.Could anyone please clarify

When you write: `var myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);` you are creating the variable `myapp` in the global scope.

> I think we should use variable only if our module is divided in multiple files

That's not necessary. You can always get your module with `angular.module("moduleName");`, avoiding thus the creation of a global variable.